# How to pass username and password of a bitbucket repository to a shell script triggered via jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

I am trying to create a Jenkins job that will trigger a shell script via the option Send files or execute commands over SSH in Jenkins.
Following is the main part of my shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
BRANCH=$1
cd /vm/deployment
git clone https://myuser@bitbucket.org/myuser/proj.git
#updating the common property files
cd /vm/deployment/swcm-properties
git reset --hard HEAD
#git pull ${BRANCH}
git fetch && git checkout ${BRANCH}
git pull
```

My problem here is that the execution fails as I am unable to pass the password and username for the repository for the clone to work.

I found an option to set the username and password as global credentials and made the following configurations:
[image: Configurtion]

I try to execute the following shell script which is saved in the server and I am getting the error ass below.

```
#!/bin/bash
git clone https://$uname:$pass@bitbucket.org/mysuer/myrepo.git

remote: Invalid username or password
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://:@bitbucket.org/****/myrepo.git/'
```

What is the best approach to pass the username and password and trigger a git clone from a bitt bucket repository using Jenkins.

Comment: can you try  this git clone https://${uname}:${pass}@bitbucket.org/${uname}/myrepo.git

Comment: @Jaganath Kamble, I get this error when I try this: fatal: repository 'https://:@bitbucket.org//myrepo.git/' not found

Answer (score 1):

Another option, if you have only one credential to manage with BitBucket, would be (with the account used by Jenkins) to register your credentials in a [Git credential helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) (as described in [Git Credential Storage](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage))

That way, Git would automatically used the associated credentials, even in the context of a Jenkins job, since your master and agent are on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to pull or build a code on Jenkins is to use plugins. "[Bitbucket Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/bitbucket/)" can do the same for you. You can use credentials which created on Jenkins. You also can add a WebHook with this plugin.There are a lot of how-to online.

Comment: I am trying to execute a script on multiple servers from a single Jenkins. I do not have a master-slave Jenkins configuration. I am not sure how the bitbucket plugin will work for me